# JQPlot Legend not showing in multiple columns even after setting numberColumns :3

Tags: jqplot, legend

I want to show Legends in multiple columns and just one row, but even after setting these properties in Legend rendererOptions, its not getting changed, and showing in only one column.
This is the code I am using:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = JSON.parse("[[65,68],[88,59],[78,68],[68,69],[88,88],[75,66]]");
            $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
            plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', obj, {
                animate: true,
                seriesDefaults: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        barWidth: 25,
                        barPadding: 2,
                        shadow: false,
                    },
                    pointLabels: {
                        show: true,
                    }
                },
                series: [
                 { label: 'English' },
                 { label: 'Hindi' },
                 { label: 'Maths' },
                 { label: 'Science' },
                 { label: 'Computers' },
                 { label: 'History' }
                ],

                seriesColors: ['#C0504D', '#1F497D', '#4BACC6', '#8064A2', '#9BBB59', '#F79646', '#948A54'],
                grid: {
                    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
                    gridLineColor: '#000000',
                    drawBorder: false,
                    shadow: false,
                    gridLineWidth: 0.5
                },
                legend: {

                    show: true,

                    location:'s![enter image description here][1]',
                    placement: 'outsideGrid',
                    shrinkGrid: true,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        numberColumns: 3,
                        numberRows : 1
                    }
                },
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                        ticks: ['FA 1', 'FA 2'],
                        tickOptions: {
                            angle: -90,
                            textColor: "#000000",
                            showGridline: true
                        },
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        min: '0',
                        max: '100',
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                        rendererOptions: { tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer },
                        ticks: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
                        tickOptions: {
                            textColor: "#000000",
                            showGridline: true,
                            formatString: "%d"
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer` in Legend options

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/1507/)

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = JSON.parse("[[65,68],[88,59],[78,68],[68,69],[88,88],[75,66]]");
            $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
            plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', obj, {
                animate: true,
                seriesDefaults: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        barWidth: 25,
                        barPadding: 2,
                        shadow: false,
                    },
                    pointLabels: {
                        show: true,
                    }
                },
                series: [
                 { label: 'English' },
                 { label: 'Hindi' },
                 { label: 'Maths' },
                 { label: 'Science' },
                 { label: 'Computers' },
                 { label: 'History' }
                ],

                seriesColors: ['#C0504D', '#1F497D', '#4BACC6', '#8064A2', '#9BBB59', '#F79646', '#948A54'],
                grid: {
                    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
                    gridLineColor: '#000000',
                    drawBorder: false,
                    shadow: false,
                    gridLineWidth: 0.5
                },
                legend: {
                     renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer, 
                    show: true,

                    location:'s![enter image description here][2]',
                    placement: 'outsideGrid',
                    shrinkGrid: true,
                    rendererOptions: {
                                numberRows : 1
                    }
                },
                axes: {
                    xaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                        ticks: ['FA 1', 'FA 2'],
                        tickOptions: {
                            angle: -90,
                            textColor: "#000000",
                            showGridline: true
                        },
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        min: '0',
                        max: '100',
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                        rendererOptions: { tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer },
                        ticks: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
                        tickOptions: {
                            textColor: "#000000",
                            showGridline: true,
                            formatString: "%d"
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

});
```

If you set  `numberColumns : 1` the legend is look like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/1508/)
It will only show first 3 series

Comment: I have been reviewing your suggested edits. I found that many of them are too minor (just formatting). Edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

Comment: @Nandu, it's weired your fiddle shows only one column with mutiple rows in any case on my computer(Chrome v32.0.1700.72 , Windows7-32bit)